# Xamarin Forms ListView text not displayed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, I'm following the official tutorial for learning Xamarin forms. While learning about navigation using Phoneword project of the following link
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/

The listview text is not appearing. Please help me!

CallHistoryPage.xaml: Here the listview is there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1"
             x:Class="App1.CallHistoryPage"
             Title="Call History">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="20, 40, 20, 20"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.PhoneNumbers}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs: SourceItem values are updated in this class.

```
namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        string translatedNumber;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void OnTranslate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            translatedNumber = PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
            {
                callButton.IsEnabled = true;
                callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                callButton.IsEnabled = false;
                callButton.Text = "Call";
            }
        }

        async void OnCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (await this.DisplayAlert(
                    "Dial a Number",
                    "Would you like to call " + translatedNumber + "?",
                    "Yes",
                    "No"))
            {
                var dialer = DependencyService.Get<IDialer>();
                if (dialer != null)
                {
                    App.PhoneNumbers.Add(translatedNumber);
                    callHistoryButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    dialer.Dial(translatedNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        async void OnCallHistory(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CallHistoryPage());
        }

    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs: Sourceitem for listview is in this class

```
namespace App1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public static IList<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

For more details please follow the link added above. Same tutorial is followed.

Comment: Show us your code pls ! How do you expect us to help if the only thing we can do is to guess the problem ...

Comment: Added the code Please help me. @FelixD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to *'tell'* `ListView` what to display.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.PhoneNumbers}" />
```

creates a `ListView` with empty cells, hence they are not displaying anything. You'll have to set the `ListView.ItemTemplate` in order to display anything

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.PhoneNumbers}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `BindingContext` within the `DataTemplate` will be the respective item from `App.PhoneNumbers`. Since the items are bare `string`s we bind to `.`, which refers to the bound element itself.

See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) for `ListView`s in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added any numbers in PhoneNumbers list. Add number first in PhoneNumbers list and then check.

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
        PhoneNumbers.Add("123456789");
        PhoneNumbers.Add("178967897");
        PhoneNumbers.Add("178945678");

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Hitesh Patel,
In MainPage.xaml.cs, you can see OnCall method. 
In OnCall method after calling every number is added to the list.
After Calling every time and navigating to CallHistoryPage I can see listitems increasing(can see the list item border increasing). 
But PhoneNumbers are not appearing

Comment: Please refer the link added to the question for more details. I followed the same tutorial. The code is same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forget to take input from user.So add this line in OnCall method

```
translatedNumber = PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
```

Try this,

```
async void OnCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        translatedNumber = PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);

        if (await this.DisplayAlert(
                "Dial a Number",
                "Would you like to call " + translatedNumber + "?",
                "Yes",
                "No"))
        {
            var dialer = DependencyService.Get<IDialer>();
            if (dialer != null)
            {
                App.PhoneNumbers.Add(translatedNumber);
                callHistoryButton.IsEnabled = true;
                dialer.Dial(translatedNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. The problem was not with values. The answer from Paul solved my problem.